# Graphic Card GeForce GT 630 installation on 64bit Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.04, graphics

I am using 64bit ubuntu 15.04 and in the hardwared; NVIDIA GeForce GT630 graphic card is attached. I have downloaded driver for this graphic card from the website given in the official website as shown in Fig.[NVIDIA-GeForce GT630-website-screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kA5k.png), I have followed every method mentioned in different sites such as

1. press `Ctrl+alt+F1`
2. Type in, `sudo service lightdm stop` and then
3. to run as root `ls -i`
4. `sh. graphic-driver.run`
5. `sudo service lightdm start`

I have crashed my Linux 15.04 3 times in this way and now I am unable to even re-install it which is a separate story. Please, help.

Comment: If you can't get a working installation how can we help you install the graphics drivers? It's never a good idea if you're a beginner to install video drivers from the web. It seems to fail a lot. If you get Ubuntu up and running again, just open the Additional Drivers app and select the NVIDIA driver there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is an easier way of installing the latest Nvidia Drivers on ubuntu.**

- Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Remove all previous installations of Nvidia with :

  `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`
- Update the repositories :

  `sudo apt-get update`
- Install the Driver:

  `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`
- Finally Reboot :

  `sudo reboot`

Installed :)

**NOTE:** Your latest driver number may not be **352** Please make sure the latest available version of the Driver for your card On [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) (352.66 =>352)

**Update:** I removed the PPA from the answer because it is not necessary to add it when installing 352.

Comment: I followed your mentioned method and it worked. Hurrah! You have no idea how many times, I crashed my system in an attempt to install this driver. I am so thankful to you Severus Tux. I wish that you may succeed in every way of your life and be helped as you helped me. Lots of love and respect for you.

Comment: @Abdul Mannan Glad to know that :) ,  If this answer solved your problem, please do not forget to click the grey tick ☑ at the left of the answer to make it green, which means [Yes, this answer is valid !](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: :) Thanks Severus Tux, I was also going through this problem. I was having some problem while updating, some sort of failed PPA. I uninstalled it and now everything is perfectly fine. I am so thankful to you.

Answer (score 2):

It is just as easy as ...

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

There is no need to do more ...

Comment: Thank you so much dear cl-nebox for your kind in time response.

Comment: @AbdulMannan: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**