# Ubuntu | GT 630 Drivers

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce, 23.10

I have installed Ubuntu, but I cannot install GT 630 graphics card driver.
How do I install it?
My monitor resolution does not change in the settings, and it is not what you need.

Ubuntu 23.10
Xeon E5-2420 v2
16 GB of RAM
NVIDIA Geforce GT 630
128 GB SSD

Comment: Show us exactly what you have tried, what you have, which version of Ubuntu. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Did you try `sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the NVidia GT630 Linux support seems to be discontinued.

The last driver that supported it was [the 390.154 version](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/390-154-driver-no-longer-works-with-kernel-6-0/230959), and the last Ubuntu version that supported it was 22.10, because Ubuntu 23.xx is based on the new kernel version 6.xx.

You can get more information on this problem from [my last year's question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1467477/51957). The other related question from 2016 [Graphic Card GeForce GT 630 installation on 64bit Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726658/graphic-card-geforce-gt-630-installation-on-64bit-ubuntu-15-04) is even more outdated.

However, the Nouveau driver still somewhat works with some quirks.

Comment: You may be able to install an older LTS Kernel from Ubuntu Mainline Kernel and then install GT630 driver.