# I installed a NVIDIA and now my screen just show a HP and Ubuntu and won't load

Tags: command-line, drivers, grub2, nvidia, hp

So I found this decade-old AIO in a yard sale and decided to buy it. It was first shipped with Windows 8 and after a slow start, I decided to switch it to Ubuntu 22.04.3 and was much faster.

I did regular maintenance on the computer and decided to install the driver since the computer doesn't find the NVIDIA driver. I followed the instructions to the official Ubuntu website https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation, and it told me to type `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` into the terminal and everything was going well. After that, I rebooted the system and first just shows the HP logo booting then it just stops with the Ubuntu and Hp logo and nothing else happens.

[HP Envy 23 AIO after Nvidia Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKemj.jpg)

I tried to activate GRUB but since i am very new to Ubuntu, I really don't know how and the things that it tells me like to press `esc` but does nothing or press `shift` but just sends me to the HP Startup Menu.

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Driver Information:
Geoforce GT 630M

Comment: That card is no longer supported. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1497262/243321 The proprietary driver that it needs won't run on the current kernels. I had this same issue and the last Ubuntu system that supports it is 20.04 with the non HWE kernel. Anything newer won't work. You can run the nouveau driver though.